# PHP: convert date string to Unix timestamp

Tags: php

Given the following strings:

- 01/01/11
- 1/1/11
- 1/1/2011
- 01/1/2011
- 1-1-2011
- etc

How do I convert these to a Unix timestamp. Note that in most cases, this will be in the format of `dd mm yyyy` with various delimiters.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Look at [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) or the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class.

**`strtotime` Example:**

```
$timestamp = strtotime('1/1/2011');
```

Each function has it's caveat. For instance, the documentation for `strtotime` states that:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats
>   are disambiguated by looking at the
>   separator between the various
>   components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is
>   assumed; whereas if the separator is a
>   dash (-) or a dot (.), then the
>   European d-m-y format is assumed.

You could also use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to capture all 3 parts and create your own timestamp using [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

**`preg_match` Example:**

```
if ( preg_match('/^(?P<day>\d+)[-\/](?P<month>\d+)[-\/](?P<year>\d+)$/', '1/1/2011', $matches) )
{
  $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, ( $matches['month'] - 1 ), $matches['day'], $matches['year']);
}
```

Comment: your regex assumes dd-mm-yyyy format, which I am not sure it is.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - Your question said: "Note that in most cases, this will be in the format of dd mm yyyy with various delimiters." so I went with that format but you could add `elseif` statements to the original one that check for different formats and make the `regex` more specific (i.e. instead of \d+ use a pattern that describes 0-12 for the month and 0-31 for the days). Of course, in the case of 1/2/13, it's impossible to tell which is which unless you know the format.

Answer (score 5):

```
$to='23.1.2014-18:16:35'
list($part1,$part2) = explode('-', $to);
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('.', $part1);
list($hours, $minutes,$seconds) = explode(':', $part2);
$timeto =  mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month, $day, $year);
echo $timeto;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

However just as a caution it will convert each and every possible string format to a unix timestamp (epoch) since it is very difficult to unambiguously parse each and every string to date-time.