# PHP Convert formatted date into unixtime

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have dates in the format Y-M-D hour-minute-second `2013-09-03 12:10:28`, but I need the unixtimestamp.

PHP has a slough of functions for transforming dates and times, but apprently none that can accept a date and its format and convert it into unixtime. The closest function I found was `mktime()`, but I would need to parse my current date into each of its components. Is there an easier way?

Comment: [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) can handle that format perfectly fine.

Comment: `echo strtotime('2013-09-03 12:10:28');`

Comment: Forget strtotime(), date(), time() and similar functions. Start using DateTime class. Example: `echo (new DateTime('2013-09-03 12:10:28'))->getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)('2013-09-03 12:10:28');

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-09-03 12:10:28');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

IMHO it is better not to use strtotime() because it tries to guess a time format. I do not like any "magic" in programming.

Comment: This is the best option as the format is explicit rather than implied.

Comment: Good if your date format is not dynamic one.

Comment: I agree with other types of format, but `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` is way too standard for "magic" to happen ;) If datetime is in [supported date and time formats](http://si1.php.net/datetime.formats)  then you don't need to worry about "magic" happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '2013-09-03 12:10:28';
echo strtotime($str);
```

> 1378228228

Answer (score 0):

You may try [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo strtotime('2013-09-03 12:10:28'); // 1378210228
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo strtotime('1/1/2013');
?>
```

Output: 1356994800 -> Unixtimestamp

Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501019/php-convert-date-string-to-unix-timestamp)