# How to change Day-D-Month-Y - Time Date Format in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I'm working with a date string in this format Wednesday 21 February 2018 - 09:35.
I'm just curious, is there an easy way to change this into a UNIX datetime format in either SQl or PHP or would I have to write a unique case for each one.

I have tried changing this with the PHP function strtotime but I can't get it to work with this specific format.

Thanks!

Comment: you can do on both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: convert date string to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501019/php-convert-date-string-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually handle this directly in MySQL, using the `STR_TO_DATE` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` functions:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE('Wednesday 21 February 2018 - 09:35', '%W %e %M %Y - %H:%i')) AS ts
FROM dual;
```

[image]

### Demo

The basic idea is to first convert your text timestamp into a formal date using `STR_TO_DATE`, then convert that date into a UNIX timestamp using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to know how to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: @CameronRose Sorry, I thought you were using MySQL (usually a good assumption with a PHP question).  No, I don't think SQL Server has the ability to parse an arbitrary timestamp like yours into a formal date.

Comment: If you're really using SQL Server, then you'll probably have to handle this in PHP, or just use ISO compliant timestamps.